# Two arguments together in if statement, shell script

Tags: shell, terminal, server

I have basic knowledge of shell scripting and I have never seen this comparison before. One of my experienced colleagues has never seen it either. The code came from and older application and has most likely been changed a couple times.

```
if [ "$1$2" = "start" ]; then
```

Short story, the shell script starts a server and is called as such:

```
./start.sh start
```

---

I would understand if it was:

```
if [ "$1" = "start" ]; then
```

If argument1 is equal to "start".

Anyone ever seen this and can provide an explanation?

Comment: If nothing else, it provides for multiple ways to start a service? I.e.: `./start.sh st art` or `./start.sh sta rt`...

Comment: So it concats them together incase of a typo?

Comment: That, or to avoid starting the server whenever the script encounters more than one argument (for whichever reason).

Comment: It would also allow, who knows why, this: `./start.sh "" start`

Comment: Or it ensures that the second argument *doesn't* exist; with `./start.sh start some-other-arg`, you wouldn't start.